# Web Crypto API using Microsoft Edge (38.14393.0.0)

Tags: javascript, encryption, promise, microsoft-edge, webcrypto-api

I am using the Web Crypto API (https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) successfully on Chrome (since first Web Crypto support), Firefox (since first Web Crypto support) and even on Safari TP (10.2) with support of a WebCrypto Liner a pollyfill for WebCrypto API (https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto-liner).

Now I want to test our code using Microsoft Edge. But encrypting and decrypting a sample ArrayBuffer already fails. Here the code:

```
var crypto = window.crypto;
if (crypto.subtle) {
    var aesGcmKey = null;
    // always create a new, random iv in production systems!!!
    var tempIv = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]);
    // needed for edge, if additional data missing decrypting is failing
    var tempAdditionalData = new Uint8Array(0);
    var dataToEncrypt = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

    // 1.) generate key
    var generateKeyPromise = crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {name: "AES-GCM", length: 256}, true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    );
    generateKeyPromise.then(function (tempKey) {
        aesGcmKey = tempKey;
        // 2.) start encryption with this key
        var encryptedDataPromise = crypto.subtle.encrypt(
            {name: "AES-GCM", iv: tempIv, additionalData: tempAdditionalData, tagLength: 128},
            aesGcmKey,
            dataToEncrypt
        );
        encryptedDataPromise.then(function (encryptedData) {
            // 3.) decrypt using same key
            var decryptedDataPromise = crypto.subtle.decrypt(
                {name: "AES-GCM", iv: tempIv, additionalData: tempAdditionalData, tagLength: 128},
                aesGcmKey,
                encryptedData
            );
            decryptedDataPromise.then(function (decryptedData) {
                // 4.) compare decrypted array buffer and inital data
                console.log('data decrypted!');
                console.log(decryptedData);
            });
            decryptedDataPromise.catch(function (error) {
                console.log('decrypting sample data failed');
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
        // if 2.) is failing
        encryptedDataPromise.catch(function (error) {
            console.log('encrypting sample data failed');
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
    // if 1.) is failing
    generateKeyPromise.catch(function (error) {
        console.log('creating aec gcm key failed');
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

This code is failing in the decrypting phase (step 3. in the code) on Edge, while its working fine on Chrome, Firefox and even Safari. The wired part it that the decryptedDataPromise is rejected with an exception but the returned data doesnt look like an exception at all:

```
[object Object] {additionalData: Uint8Array {...}, iv: Uint8Array {...}, name: "AES-GCM", tagLength: 128}
```

Does anybody have a clue why this fails on Microsoft Edge?

Comment: this live example https://diafygi.github.io/webcrypto-examples/ shows that AES-GCM works in Edge. So It will be due to some small difference in the parameters. Could you try with a IV of size 12 instead of 16?

Comment: further to the above comment, it seems you need `var tempAdditionalData = new Uint8Array(1);` note: 1 not 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in comments, changing IV to size 12 instead of 16 and additional data to contain `1` instead of `0` fix the issue in Edge

```
var tempIv = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]);
var tempAdditionalData = new Uint8Array(1);
```

Your comment about additional data *"// needed for edge, if additional data missing decrypting is failing"* is really not needed. `additionalData` can be void

I was looking in MSDN about [encrypt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302329(v=vs.85).aspx) operation, but it is not documented this behaviour. So I think the implementation of WebCrypto is not mature enough and still there are small bugs

Answer (score 1):

In Edge 41 the original code produces the same behavior. 
Setting `tempAdditionalData` to `null` however solves the problem and decrypt succeeds.